# Xamarin Unable to create Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, xamarin

I followed the Xamarin tutorial to open another activity but I receive an error message saying: the type or namespace name"Intent" could not be found(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BaRA4.png)

May I know if there is anything missing or wrong in my code? Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure you have referenced `using Android.Content;` on top of your activity

Comment: Thank you, you are right. I just tried adding the referenced and the error has been removed!

Comment: @cg1991 good that now is sorted, can you mark this as the accepted answer if it helped you?

Comment: What do you need if using Xamarin Forms? Which NuGet package should you download and which namespace should you be using?

Answer (score -1):

You Need code something like this ...

```
 home.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {   //here home is a button 
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(LoginOption.this,HomeActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

You Must need two activity first where your butoon exist, to open another activity `Intent intent=new Intent(LoginOption.this,HomeActivity.class);` here first activity is loginoption activity where my button is exist and another home activity which will be open after clicking event.